# Getting Triple quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, rest, backend

Android mobile app is sending the body in a API of Nodejs with the request data as

```
{ 
    "openingHour":['"02:00PM"','"03:00PM"']
}
```

and in the backend system I am unable to remove either single quote or double quote using JS only.

my requirement is

```
{ 
    "openingHour":["02:00PM","03:00PM"]
}

OR 

{ 
    "openingHour":['02:00PM','03:00PM']
}
```

how can i achieve the above requirements.

Comment: I recommend that the backend be fixed to provide valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the substring function to remove the leading and trailing quote from each entry and build a new array out of it.

Using the map function you can iterate over each element in the `openingHour` array, applying that expression, and use the array returned from `map` to assign it back to the json

```js
let json = {
  "openingHour": ['"02:00PM"', '"03:00PM"']
}

console.log('before', json)

let newOpeningHourArray = json.openingHour.map(time =>
  time.substring(1, time.length - 1))

json.openingHour = newOpeningHourArray

console.log('after', json)
```